# How to add new file types in Ektron

Tags: ektron

Ektron 8.01 SP1

I have a client that wants to upload .m4a files.  I added the extension in the settings and verified that its now in the AssetManagement.config file but I still get an error when attempting to save, I get the "invalid extension..." popup error message.

Is there another setting somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AssetManagement config only applies to DMS assets. If you're adding "files" to the library, that config is found in Library > Library (root folder) > Properties.

If you *are* using the DMS, did you verify your changes in Workarea > Settings > Asset Server Setup?

Comment: It was the image folder properties.  That was FAST!